# Python - get repeat matches in two lists

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to match two lists, but I want to pick up the repeat matches too. I can't use set because that would only give me {3} in my second example below.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [3,3,4,5]
return [3,4]

a = [1,2,3,3]
b = [3,3,4,5]
return [3,3]
```

Comment: `c=[x for x in a if x in b]`

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre I don't think that's what he meant. `a=[3,3];b=[3]` is only supposed to match once I think. It's a a list intersection.

Comment: I had a doubt, or I would have answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list comprehesion to check and return every item in `a` if it exists in `b` like below:

```
[item for item in a if item in b]
```

If you want only the elements that are in both `a` and `b` (to cover the cases mentioned by @kabanus in the comment), you can use the following:

```
[item for item in set(a) for i in range(min(a.count(item), b.count(item)))]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = [3, 3, 4, 5]
>>> [item for item in set(a) for i in range(min(a.count(item), b.count(item)))]
[3, 4]
>>>
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 3]
>>> b = [3, 3, 4, 5]
>>> [item for item in set(a) for i in range(min(a.count(item), b.count(item)))]
[3, 3]
>>> 
>>> a = [3, 3, 4]
>>> b = [4, 4, 3]
>>> [item for item in set(a) for i in range(min(a.count(item), b.count(item)))]
[3, 4]
```

Comment: See my comment to the OP. `a=[3,3];b=[3]` should only match once I think, like an intersection, you will match it twice.

Comment: Your function fails for `a=[3,3,4];b=[4,4,3]`, (4 appears twice) in result, but almost. I'll up vote if you make it work. The condition is too trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like (if order doesn't matter), Python 2:

```
from collections import Counter

a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [3,3,4,5]
ca=Counter(a)
cb=Counter(b)
print sum([[x]*min(ca[x],cb[x]) for x in set(a)],[])
```

This should return the list of all repeating matches the number of time they repeat, with no particular ordering beyond grouping together same elements. The output for the above example is:

```
[3,4]
```

I'm assuming you missed 4. The other example you have yields what you posted:

```
[3,3]
```

Comment: Yes I did miss 4 (edited), I think this does what I wanted to do, thanks!